# Calculating distance in m in xyz between GPS coordinates that are close together

Tags: gps, matlab

I have a set of GPS Coordinates and I want to find the speed required for a UAV to travel between them. Doing this by calculating distance in x y z and then dividing by time to travel - m/s.

I know the great circle distance but I assume this will be incorrect since they are all relatively close together?

Is there an accurate way to do this?

Comment: Define 'close' - hundreds of miles? meters? What, if any GIS software are you using / have access to? Is z a significant factor?

Comment: Within 10m. I am not using GIS. Programming it myself as part of a matlab programme. I am thinking I can use a flat earth approximation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Distance between GPS coordinates](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/21051/distance-between-gps-coordinates)

Comment: Within 10m I'd just use Euclidean distance -- not because it's more accurate than great circle distance for small measurements, but because the math is simpler :)